# Creating vector of custom complex number class using std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, iterator

I am new to coding and currently learning C++ to get started, so please excuse my narrow knowledge and very possible mistakes in code and general C++ lingo.

I have written a class of complex numbers called `ComplexNumber` with member variables being `double re` and `double im` with the obvious meanings. This class has a constructor, an empty constructor, a copy constructor, a destructor etc.

Using this I am now meaning to write a class `ComplexVector` of vectors with entries from `ComplexNumber`. For now I have defined the member variables to be a vector `std::vector<ComplexNumber> vec` and a size `int size`. Additionally I would like to define a member function `void print()`, again with the obvious meaning. The code I have so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "complex.h"

class ComplexVector {
  private:
    std::vector<ComplexNumber> vec;
    int size;

  public:
    ComplexVector(std::vector<ComplexNumber> vector, int n){ //constructor
      size = n;
      vec = vector;
    };
    ComplexVector(){ //empty constructor
      size = 0;
      vec = {};
    };
    void print() const;
    ~ComplexVector(); //destructor
    ComplexVector(const ComplexVector& v); //copy constructor
    ComplexVector addition(ComplexVector w);      //
    ComplexVector subtraction(ComplexVector w);   // i am not worrying about these for now
    ComplexVector scale(ComplexNumber z);         //
};
```

with defnitions

```
void ComplexVector::print() const {
  for(std::vector<ComplexNumber>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++){
    std::cout << *it << " ";
  };
  std::cout << std::endl;
};

ComplexVector::~ComplexVector(){
  std::cout << "calling destructor" << std::endl;
};

ComplexVector::ComplexVector(const ComplexVector& v){
  size = v.size;
  vec = v.vec;
};
```

Here is where I am getting a compiling error: in the definition of the `print` my compiler tells me

```
error: no viable conversion from '__wrap_iter<std::__1::vector<ComplexNumber, std::__1::allocator<ComplexNumber>
      >::const_pointer>' to '__wrap_iter<std::__1::vector<ComplexNumber, std::__1::allocator<ComplexNumber> >::pointer>'
  for(std::vector<ComplexNumber>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++){
```

which I am not quite sure how to deal with. I have read something about certain member functions having to be defined for `ComplexNumber` to be used in an `std::vector`. I also played around with defining iterators inside of `ComplexVector` but this did not solve the problem. From my (to be fair very narrow) perspective there should be an iterator for `vec` and also corresponding `begin()`and `end()` functions. I have checked if I am passing arguments of the right type a thousand times, but I must be overlooking something.

One more thing to note is that I am very much aware that this is probably an extremely inefficient way to define a class like this. I have looked at multiple examples which used pointers to an array as the main member variable. I am surely going to implement something of that type next, but for now I want to understand where the mistake in my current code is. So thanks in advance for any answers.

One side question: I don't think I have understood the concept of a destructor very well (to be fair I haven't spent much time reading about it yet), but if anyone has a quick intuition about them, which he/she wants to share, that would be highly appreciated.

Also if you have any comments on style and/or other improvements of my code, I would appreciate it if you could share them.

Thank you!

Edit: Here is the `ComplexNumber`class

```
class ComplexNumber {
  private:
    double re;
    double im;
  public:
    ComplexNumber(double x, double y){
      re = x;
      im = y;
    };
    ComplexNumber(){
      re = im = 0;
    };
    ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber& z);
    void print() const;
};
```

and definitions

```
void ComplexNumber::print() const {
    if(im > 0){
      std::cout << re << "+" << im << "i" << std::endl;
    } else if(im < 0){
      std::cout << re << im << "i" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << re << std::endl;
    };
};

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber& z){
  re = z.re;
  im = z.im;
};
```

And a main method:

```
int main() {

  std::vector<ComplexNumber> v1 = {ComplexNumber(1,2), ComplexNumber(4,2)};
  int n = 2;
  ComplexVector w1(v1,n);
  w1.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `size` member variable in your class.  Just use `vector::size()`.  The same thing with a destructor -- no need for one.

Comment: The code you show is not the code you actually compile. The error message mentions `std::list<ComplexNumber>::iterator`, which doesn't appear in the code shown.

Comment: tl;dr; Would you mind making a [mcve] and explain what its purpose is?

Comment: Make it `for (const auto& number: vec) { std::cout << number << " "; };`

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik, I've changed it and I will try your suggestion :)

Comment: Your `ComplexNumber` class sounds too, um, complex.  If you add it to your question (which you should do anyway, see [mre]) we can probably tell you how to simplify it.

Comment: Take a look at the [Rule of Three/Five/Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). All of your destructors and constructors do nothing special and can be automatically generated by the compiler (assuming you get rid of `size`) and so you should get rid of them (following the Rule of Zero)

Comment: Also about the `size` member, it's currently possible to call your code like `ComplexVector(std::vector<ComplexNumber>{x, y, z}, 10000)` which is obviously wrong. `std::vector` already tracks its own size, no need to create ambiguity and waste space.

Comment: @thore That's why you should never create extraneous variables to track sizes of vectors or other containers.  There is a good chance that the extraneous variable will not hold the correct value for whatever reason, get out of sync, etc..  A vector knows its size already by calling `size()` -- no errors, no mistakes.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's all very helpful advice!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
void ComplexVector::print() const {
  for(std::vector<ComplexNumber>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++){
    std::cout << *it << " ";
  };
  std::cout << std::endl;
};
```

Notice that the function is marked `const`. This means any members of the class are treated as const qualified inside the method (i.e. you are not allowed to modify them). Thus when you call `vec.begin()` you are calling the const version of `begin()` on vector. This returns `const_iterator` not an `iterator`.

```
  std::vector<ComplexNumber>::iterator it = vec.begin()
                              ^^^^^^^^ should be const_iterator
```

A better way to solve this is to use `auto` and let the compiler work out the correct type:

```
   auto it = vec.begin()
```

So the function becomes:

```
void ComplexVector::print() const {
  for(std::vector<ComplexNumber>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++){
    std::cout << *it << " ";
  };
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

or with auto:

```
void ComplexVector::print() const {
  for(auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++){
    std::cout << *it << " ";
  };
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

or you can improve this by using the new version of `for()`

```
void ComplexVector::print() const {
  for(auto const& item: vec){
    std::cout << item << " ";
  };
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Note: When your code works. You can ask for a review on style at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

---

Follow up based on comments:
Try:

```
class ComplexNumber
{
     ...... 
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, ComplexNumber const& data) {
         data.print(); // You want to change this
                      // so you can pass the stream to print.
         return str;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but for some reason I am getting an `invalid operands to binary expression` error in the line that prints `*it` even if I adjust the code, doesn't this usually occur, when one accidentally tries to "print" something declared as a function?

Comment: That means it does not know how to print a const version of the complex number type. Have a look at `operator<<()` for your complex type (it does not look like you even have one so you may need to add it) see if it takes the parameters by const reference.

Comment: @thore. See the addition I just added to the end of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much; this works perfectly. I will make sure to read up on these operators :)

Comment: @thore Now it works get a proper review here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com